# dotted arrow in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I drew the following commutative diagram with `tikz` (I can't use `tikz-cd` since it's not on my version of LaTeX ; I tried to install it but doesn't seem to work)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
     \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \node (X) at (1,1){$X$};
        \node (A) at (0,0){$A$};
        \node (B) at (2,0){$B$};
        \node (axb) at (1,0){$A \times B$};
        \path[->,font=\scriptsize,>=angle 90]
        (axb) edge node[below]{$x_1$} (A)
        (axb) edge node[below]{$p_B$} (B)
        (X) edge node[above]{$p_A$} (A)
        (X) edge node[above]{$p_B$} (B)
        (X) edge node[left]{$w$} (axb);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

I need the w arrow to be dotted, how can I do that ?

Comment: Since it seems you don't have the standard LaTeX versions, please specify which one you have. Also, please make your example minimal but include all the meaningful stuff from `documentclass` to `end{document}`

Comment: Have you tried the option `edge[dotted]`?

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out...

Comment: However if you had an idea why tikz-cd doesn't work, I would be grateful

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: @AboAmmar, ups, when I upload ma answer I didn't see your comment :(. Now I need to slightly improve it :)

Comment: @Bernard Ubuntu 16.04 my distribution

Comment: Do you mean you have the LaTeX distribution of Ubuntu?

Comment: I think so. I installed texlive 2016 yesterday but it didn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: `\draw [dotted,arrow] (node1) -- (node2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
doted line was solved by *AboAmar* comment  slightly before my answer ... so I add some of topic issues. With use of the library `\quotes` you can make your code more concise and also gives better positioning of edge labels:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node (X) at (1,1){$X$};
\node (A) at (0,0){$A$};
\node (B) at (2,0){$B$};
\node (axb) at (1,0){$A \times B$};
\path[-angle 90,font=\scriptsize]
(axb) edge ["$x_1$"]   (A)
(axb) edge ["$p_B$" '] (B)
(X) edge   edge ["$p_A$" '] (A)
(X)   edge ["$p_B$"]   (B)
(X)   edge[dotted,% <-- added
                  "$w$" '] (axb);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea why I can't use the package tikz-cd ?

Comment: @Asinus, sorry, I haven't insight in your installation of LaTeX. I use MikTeX with enabled installation missing packages on-the-fly. It works fine.